# openpyxl - can not iterate over excel rows

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a problem with iteration with openpyxl

[image]

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pfad,read_only=True)
sheet = wb.active
max_row = sheet.max_row    
for row in sheet["A1":"B4"]:
    print(row)
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.coordinate)
```

I should get the response of the coordinates from A1 to B4.
But instead I got only A1 to B1:

```
(<ReadOnlyCell 'Tabelle1'.A1>, <ReadOnlyCell 'Tabelle1'.B1>)
A1
B1
```

If I used **for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1,max_row=4,min_col=1,max_col=2)**:
instead of *for row in sheet["A1":"B4"]*, I got the same result

That means, I can not iterate through the 2., 3. and 4. rows

I don´t know why it dosen´t work. Maybe I have ignored something?
Thanks for any help!

========================
the problem is solved
It is one part of a function and I inserted "return" the wrong way....

=========================
in addition

the function looks like:

```
def excel_to_dict(pfad):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(pfad,read_only=True)
    sheet = wb.active
    list1 = []
    max_row = sheet.max_row
    print(max_row)
    for row in sheet["A1":f"A{max_row}"]:
        print(row)
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.coordinate)
            c_value = cell.value
            print(c_value)
            list1.append(c_value)

        return list1
```

see...? wrong indentaion bevor **return**
so only the first row was returned....
I have changed the indentaion so everything is ok...

Comment: no, 3 Rows...I have added the screenshot. The result of "sheet.max_row" is also 4

Comment: got it! It is one part of a function and I used "return" the wrong way....

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the use of the function.

Comment: @CharlieClark yeah I have updated the question

Comment: `values = [row[0] for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1, values_only=True)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `sheet.rows` to get all rows

```
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("excel.xlsx", read_only=True)
>>> sheet = wb.active
>>> rows = sheet.rows
>>> for row in rows:
...     print(row)
... 
(<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.A1>, <ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.B1>)
(<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.A2>, <ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.B2>)
(<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.A3>, <ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.B3>)
(<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.A4>, <ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.B4>)
```